# Simple vector storage issue in for loop (R)

Tags: r, for-loop

I often don't use for loops and am stumped on a simple issue. I am randomizing treatments for an experiment, and am creating a master treatment list (which samples get which treatment on which week). There are only 4 treatments, the experiment lasts 12 weeks, so I am randomizing the 4 treatments 3x times.

Since I have many samples to do this for, I want to use a for loop to do this for me many times, and store a dataset of each treatment design.

I am having trouble actually storing the information correctly. I have tested all the code in the loop, and it works independently, just not in loop.

```
treatments = as.numeric(c(1:4))
sample_reps = 45

store = c()
for (i in 1:sample_reps){
  weeks1_4 = sample(treatments)
  weeks5_8 = sample(treatments)
  weeks9_12 = sample(treatments)
  
  set = c(weeks1_4,weeks5_8,weeks9_12)
  store[i] = rbind(store,set)
}
```

The output always gives me this warning:

```
In store[i] <- rbind(store, set) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Here is an example of what I would want to see:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
  1    3    4    2    4    2    3    1    2     3     1    4
  4    2    1    3    2    1    3    4    3     4     2    1
...etc
```

What simple error am I making? Despite what it might seem, I have looked pretty hard for this basic answer!

Answer (score 0):

Apologize for my misunderstanding again.  To be clear, your target output is a matrix with 45 rows and 12 columns.  Each row consists of 3 `1:4` samples concatenated together.  This code will do that:

```
samples <- c(replicate(3 * sample_reps, sample(1:4)))
output <- matrix(samples, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
output
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    4    2    3    1    2    3    1    4    3     2     4     1
 [2,]    4    3    2    1    4    1    2    3    4     2     3     1
 [3,]    1    4    3    2    3    2    1    4    3     4     2     1
 [4,]    2    1    4    3    2    4    3    1    1     3     4     2
```

RSVP if that meets your needs.

Comment: Apologies for my miscommunication. I need the series of random vector 1:4 replicated 3 times! So basically, every 4 weeks has to have each of the four treatments possible. Each row corresponds to a replicate of the same processing algorithm (but in a different random order)

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to your code to enhance readability and generalization.

1. It is better to have letters for treatments and number for samples (less confusing which and which)
2. the set seed is for reproducibility and does not affect the randomness if you lose the file storing this table after the experiment start Knowing the seed you can reproduce it

```
treatments = letters[1:4]
samples = 45

store = c()
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:samples){
  weeks1_4 = paste0(sample(treatments,4),collapse = ", ")
  weeks5_8 = paste0(sample(treatments,4),collapse = ", ")
  weeks9_12 = paste0(sample(treatments,4),collapse = ", ")
  
  sample_i = data.frame(sample=paste0("sample_",i),weeks1_4,weeks5_8,weeks9_12)
  store = rbind(store,sample_i)
}

head(store)

    sample   weeks1_4   weeks5_8  weeks9_12
1 sample_1 c, d, a, b c, b, d, a c, a, b, d
2 sample_2 b, a, d, c d, a, c, b a, d, c, b
3 sample_3 c, b, a, d a, b, d, c b, a, c, d
4 sample_4 a, c, b, d a, c, d, b b, c, a, d
5 sample_5 a, c, d, b d, b, a, c a, d, b, c
6 sample_6 c, a, b, d a, c, d, b a, c, d, b
```

or

```
store = c()
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:samples){
  weeks1_4 = sample(treatments,4)
  weeks5_8 = sample(treatments,4)
  weeks9_12 = sample(treatments,4)
  
  sample_i = data.frame(sample=paste0("sample_",i),weeks1_4,weeks5_8,weeks9_12)
  store = rbind(store,sample_i)
}

head(store)

    sample weeks1_4 weeks5_8 weeks9_12
1 sample_1        c        c         c
2 sample_1        d        b         a
3 sample_1        a        d         b
4 sample_1        b        a         d
5 sample_2        b        d         a
6 sample_2        a        a         d
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional coding standards! Also, like I told the person above, apologies for my miscommunication. I need the series of random vector 1:4 replicated 3 times! So basically, every 4 weeks has to have each of the four treatments possible. Each row corresponds to a replicate of the same processing algorithm (but in a different random order). My example may be helpful?